# selenium webdriver: upload file by drag and drop

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

On a web page I'm trying to test, we implemented drag and drop file upload. I've looked at the drag and drop API for selenium action chain API. It looks like it supports only dragging and dropping between 2 elements on a page. How to emulate dragging from a file manager?

Comment: [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) has windows GUI interactions, try there.

Comment: @guy Thanks but I'm looking for a programming solution based on selenium.

Answer (score 4):

To perform an HTML5 file drop with Selenium:

```java
static final String JS_DROP_FILE =
    "var tgt=arguments[0],e=document.createElement('input');e.type='" +
    "file';e.addEventListener('change',function(event){var dataTrans" +
    "fer={dropEffect:'',effectAllowed:'all',files:e.files,items:{},t" +
    "ypes:[],setData:function(format,data){},getData:function(format" +
    "){}};var emit=function(event,target){var evt=document.createEve" +
    "nt('Event');evt.initEvent(event,true,false);evt.dataTransfer=da" +
    "taTransfer;target.dispatchEvent(evt);};emit('dragenter',tgt);em" +
    "it('dragover',tgt);emit('drop',tgt);document.body.removeChild(e" +
    ");},false);document.body.appendChild(e);return e;";

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://html5demos.com/file-api");

WebElement drop_area = driver.findElement(By.id("holder"));

JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript(JS_DROP_FILE, new Object[] {
        drop_area
    }).sendKeys("C:\\image.png");
```

Comment: Please, could you tell us what is the source of your solution ?

Comment: @Andrea Borgogelli Avveduti, I wrote the solution. Have a look here for the api: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API

Answer (score 0):

Use AWT [Robot](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class for performing drag and drop:

```java
Robot robot=new Robot();
// drag
robot.mouseMove(x1, y1);
robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
// drop
robot.mouseMove(x2, y2);
robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
```

Answer (score 0):

AutoIt has the DLL wrapper. I use it directly from C#/Selenium code.

Answer (score 0):

Drop file using `jsExecutor`

```java
public void dropFile(File filePath, WebElement target) {
    if (!filePath.exists())
        throw new WebDriverException("File not found: " + filePath.toString());

    JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) getDriver();

    String JS_DROP_FILE =
        "var target = arguments[0]," +
        "    offsetX = arguments[1]," +
        "    offsetY = arguments[2]," +
        "    document = target.ownerDocument || document," +
        "    window = document.defaultView || window;" +
        "" +
        "var input = document.createElement('INPUT');" +
        "input.type = 'file';" +
        "input.style.display = 'none';" +
        "input.onchange = function () {" +
        "  var rect = target.getBoundingClientRect()," +
        "      x = rect.left + (offsetX || (rect.width >> 1))," +
        "      y = rect.top + (offsetY || (rect.height >> 1))," +
        "      dataTransfer = { files: this.files };" +
        "" +
        "  ['dragenter', 'dragover', 'drop'].forEach(function (name) {" +
        "    var evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvent');" +
        "    evt.initMouseEvent(name, !0, !0, window, 0, 0, 0, x, y, !1, !1, !1, !1, 0, null);" +
        "    evt.dataTransfer = dataTransfer;" +
        "    target.dispatchEvent(evt);" +
        "  });" +
        "" +
        "  setTimeout(function () { document.body.removeChild(input); }, 25);" +
        "};" +
        "document.body.appendChild(input);" +
        "return input;";

    WebElement input = (WebElement) jse.executeScript(JS_DROP_FILE, target, 0, 0);
    input.sendKeys(filePath.getAbsoluteFile().toString());
    waitFor(ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf(input));
}
```